# How send token with Passport-VKontakte (social auth)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, passport.js, vk

In my app works auth VK, but for understand who is site visitor, need send him token while he click auth vk. How send token to user with passport-vkontakte?

```
app.get('/auth/vk',
  passport.authenticate('vkontakte'),
  function(req, res){

});

app.get('/auth/vk/callback',
  passport.authenticate('vkontakte', {
    failureRedirect: '/auth/vk',
    successRedirect: '/'
  })
);
```

p.s: doc https://github.com/stevebest/passport-vkontakte

Comment: maybe need add token in strategy social auth?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

vkontakte (social) send own token. In strategy can take token vkontakte.